# WordPress Query: Only showing first ID when using variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am at a loss as to why my query is not working as expected.

I have a variable `$id_list` which prints a list of post ID's I want to show.

$id_list is a comma separated list of post ID's. This is converted from an array of post ID's chosen on an ACF option page.

The array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [center_post] => 23836 ) 
[1] => Array ( [center_post] => 23716 ) 
[2] => Array ( [center_post] => 3344 ) 
)
```

The code to turn the array into a comma seperated list:

```
$centre_arr = get_field('centre_posts', 'option');
$final = "";
foreach($centre_arr as $innerarray){
  foreach($innerarray as $id){
  $final .= $id.", ";
  }
}

$id_list = substr($final,0,-2);
```

When I `echo $id_list;` I get a comma seperated list of ID's e.g. '23836, 23716, 3344'. If I paste that output directly into the query to replace `$id_list` then all works fine.

My WordPress query looks like this:

```
<?php

$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'post_type' => array('features', 'reviews'),
'orderby' => 'post__in', 
'post__in' => array( $id_list )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

This is only returning the first post in the array and none other.

But if I paste the returned text from `$id_list` into the array then I get all of the posts returned from the query as expected.

I've tried to echo within the query but this doesn't work.

Comment: What you get in $id_list?

Comment: A list of post ID's e.g. '23836, 23716, 3344' - when I paste into the query as plain text like this: `'post__in' => array( 23836, 23716, 3344 )` - then it shows the three posts as expected.

Comment: Try to give more info about `$id_list`. It does not seem to be the same (what you manually put and what `$id_list` is returning). A bigger part of your code could help more

Comment: Edited to give more info about `$id_list`.

Answer (score 0):

So, a long way round but I solved by exploding back to an array...

```
$id_list_arr = explode(" ",$id_list);

$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'post_type' => array('features', 'reviews'),
'orderby' => 'post__in', 
'post__in' =>  $id_list_arr
);
```